# Is there a workaround for implicit template argument deduction when none are provided?

Tags: c++, api, templates, c++14

So far I don't know if it possible at all, but I'd be glad if it was.
So the context of the question is a way of declaring an API in a way to make a function more self-explanatory. I would take for example ASIO in particular.
The way it declares asynchronous functions is kind of ambigous and relies on the comments or documentation:

```
/**
* @CompletionTokenT - completion token or a callable with operator()(size_t, asio::error_type)
*/
template <typename CompletionTokenT>
constexpr auto some_async_func(params, CompletionTokenT &&token);
```

I think it would be more convenient and consistent to have types or return arguments as a part of the funciton signature. For example:

```
template <typename TokenT>
constexpr auto some_async_func(params, completion<TokenT, size_t, asio::error_type> completion);
```

This makes requirements for a completion callable more obvious. **BUT**. Now it becomes very inconvenient to use, since a compiler would not be able to deduce the types.
I tried experimenting with an intermediate class with template implicit conversion operator, like

```
template <typename TokenT>
struct token_impl
{
   template <typename ... ArgsT>
   operator completion<TokenT, ArgsT...>();
};
```

But the `completion_token` has to be deduced first in order to make an implicit conversion, so it does not work (duh).

- *Is there some hack to circumvent implicit deduction?* So the following would compile:

```
some_async_func(params, make_completion([](size_t, asio::error_type){});
some_async_func(params, make_completion(asio::use_future));
```

---

Another option might be to use type erasure and provide a wrapper `completion<int, asio::error_type>`. But that would require additional dynamic allocations.

- *What magnitude of overhead would that option have in comparison with a tempate `typename CompletionTokenT` version?*

---

Here is one workaround that will enable the ease of use, but require a library provider to add a helper function:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class TCompletionTokenT, typename TokenT, typename ... T>
constexpr auto some_async_func(params p, TCompletionTokenT<TokenT, T...> &&completion)
{
   return some_async_func(p, completion<TokenT, int>(std::forward<TCompletionTokenT<TokenT, T...>>(completion)));
}
```

---

Here is an example which does not compile (at least with MinGW64)

```
template <typename TokenT>
struct completion_token{};

template <typename TokenT, typename ... Args>
class completion
{
public:
    completion(completion_token<TokenT>)
    {}
};

template <typename TokenT>
void deduce(completion<TokenT, int>)
{}

struct use_sync{};

int main() {

    deduce(completion_token<use_sync>());
}
```

Errors:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe   -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/completion_token.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\completion_token.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/completion_token.dir/main.cpp.obj -c ../main.cpp
../main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../main.cpp:119:40: error: no matching function for call to 'deduce(completion_token<use_sync>)'
  119 |     deduce(completion_token<use_sync>());
      |                                        ^
../main.cpp:111:6: note: candidate: 'template<class TokenT> void deduce(completion<TokenT, int>)'
  111 | void deduce(completion<TokenT, int>)
      |      ^~~~~~
../main.cpp:111:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../main.cpp:119:40: note:   'completion_token<use_sync>' is not derived from 'completion<TokenT, int>'
  119 |     deduce(completion_token<use_sync>());
      |                                        ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This makes me curious why substitution for a candidate failed since there is a constructor.

Comment: How about constraining the token type with a concept instead?

Comment: @yurikilochek it should be possible with at least C++14

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: Why do you think they *created* concepts? If you could state this sort of thing in C++14, we wouldn't need concepts because *that's what they're for*.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. it do work here https://godbolt.org/z/rhfqEPzTh

Comment: @appleapple I added an example of a usage and what's happening. In your example you *explicitly* specified the arguments. But this question is about an implicit deduction when they are not provided. For example, if you pass a lambda, there m-m-might be a way to implicitly deduce those types using some elaborate traits class. But when you pass `make_completion(asio::use_future)`, there is no obvious way (or maybe no way at all) to deduce `Args...`. Hence the question

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik why completion need to know `Args`? can you give more info? (and it'd be good if you normalize all the function names in the question (like `deduce -> some_async_func`, if I guess correctly))

Comment: @appleapple this is an attempt to enhance function declarations that utilize the *Universal Asynchronous Model*. That is, for completion/continuation you can pass a callable that accepts the result arguments and will be called upon completion. But you can also invoke a function with a tag. For example `asio::use_future` will configure a function to return `std::future<Args...>` and fulfil it upon completion. The call `some_async_function(asio::use_future)` will not provide the compiler with `Args...` to instantiate `std::future<Args...>` with.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik not sure, but what you describe looks like function overloading for me.